# Trigger email when cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to trigger an email with an attachment when a cell color is changed.

The issue is that I am trying to retrieve info from different cells.

If I change color in C7, the xMailBody will be data from A8, C5 & B3.
Which would return Shariffa, 2 Aug 23.

If I change color in H31 to K31, The xMailBody will be A31, H29 to K29 & B27.
Which would return Rae, 7 to 10 Nov 23.

How Excel looks.
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xDateSelected As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set xDateSelected = Range("date1").Value
    Set Mydate = Intersect(Target, xDateSelected)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    
    If Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

    ' Set this to the exact color or flip the statement so it's:
    ' If Target.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim staff As String
    Dim date1 As String
    
    r = 0
    c = 0
    While Target.Offset(r, 0) <> ""
        r = r - 1
    Wend
    While Target.Offset(0, c) <> ""
        c = c - 1
    Wend
    
    'These move through the row (and then the column) until a non empty cell is found

    staff = Target.Offset(0, c).Value
    date1 = Target.Offset(r, 0).Value & Target.Offset(r - 2, 0).Value

    'Get the string values; need to append the two day then date values

    End If
    
    If Not Mydate Is Nothing Then
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

        'code to retrieve content from affected cells and putting into email content ie "staff name" is applying for leave on "date"
      
        xMailBody = "Hi there Priscilla" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Name: " & Range("A" & Target.Row).Value & " is applying for Ad-hoc leave on " & Range("date1" & Target.Row).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Reason: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Thank you" & vbNewLine 'calling out and placing values of each col into email body

        With xMailItem
            .To = "foong.jia.yi1@nhcs.com.sg"
            .Subject = "Applying for Ad-hoc leave "
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
            .Display
        End With
        Set xRgSel = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        Set xMailItem = Nothing
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you haven't posted the exact sub you're using, but assuming it's Worksheet_Change, it will not trigger due to cell format changes. Instead, use Worksheet_SelectionChange for this.

If you assume the cells will always be blank except for the headers you want to extract, then iterating until you reach the non-empty cell would work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0) Then 
' Set this to the exact color or flip the statement so it's:
' If Target.Interior.Color <> RGB(0,0,0) Then
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim staff As String
    Dim date As String
    r = 0
    c = 0
    While Target.Offset(r,0) <> ""
        r = r - 1
    Wend
    While Target.Offset(0,c) <> ""
        c = c - 1
    Wend
' These move through the row (and then the column) until a non empty cell is found
    staff = Target.Offset(0,c).Value
    date = Target.Offset(r,0).Value & Target.Offset(r-2,0).Value
' Get the string values; need to append the two day then date values
End If
End Sub
```

Let me know if this works.

**Edit:** In the case of the selection of multiple dates, the Change event will trigger each time the color is changed. Thinking about it, it might be better for you to create a FormControl button and link the macro to that so you don't have an email getting sent out immediately after a cell color is changed.

**Edit 2:** Here's the updated code from your revised question. Let me know if this works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' Start with the conditional
If Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0) Then

Dim xDateSelected As Range
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xMailItem As Object
Dim xMailBody As String

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim staff As String
Dim date1 As String

r = 0
c = 0
While Target.Offset(r, 0) = ""
    r = r - 1
Wend
While Target.Offset(0, c) = ""
    c = c - 1
Wend
'These move through the row (and then the column) until a non empty cell is found

staff = Target.Offset(0, c).Value
date1 = Target.Offset(r, 0).Value & Target.Offset(r - 2, c).Value
'I use r-2, c here to get the date, assuming it is a merged cell which have weird behaviour
'Get the string values; need to append the two day then date values

Set xDateSelected = Range(date1).Value ' Keep in mind you must either reference the cell itself 
' or a variable storing a string with the cell reference

Set Mydate = Intersect(Target, xDateSelected)
ActiveWorkbook.Save

If Not Mydate Is Nothing Then
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
'code to retrieve content from affected cells and putting into email content ie "staff name" is applying for leave on "date"

    xMailBody = "Hi there Priscilla" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Name: " & staff & " is applying for Ad-hoc leave on " & date1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Reason: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Thank you" & vbNewLine 'calling out and placing values of each col into email body


    With xMailItem
        .To = "foong.jia.yi1@nhcs.com.sg"
        .Subject = "Applying for Ad-hoc leave "
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
    End With
    Set xRgSel = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Set xMailItem = Nothing
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, yes that is correct the sub I used was Worksheet_Change. I have tried the codes you provided but it returns an error message. Compile error: expected: Then or GoTo

Comment: And the If Target.Interior.Color = RGB (255, 255, 0) is highlighted in red. @Alexander

Comment: Ah apologies, you need to add a then to the end of that line. I’ve edited my answer

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have edited my original code above. The email was triggered but it doesnt matter if the color of the cell changes. As long as any cell is selected it will trigger the email and the body of the email is empty. Could you assist? @Alexander

Comment: @shariffa Seems to me the second If statement is not within the first one, likely causing the email to trigger. I will edit it later if you don't get a chance to try it out before then

Comment: @shariffa Edited, go ahead and try that.

Comment: Hi, the code does not seem to retrieve the staff name. For example: If I change color in H31 to K31, the xMailBody will retrieve data from cells A31, H31 & B27. Instead of coming out as Name: Rae is applying for Ad-hoc leave on 10.  It comes out as Name: (blank) is applying for Ad-hoc leave on 10. @alexander

Comment: i was also hoping to retrieve the data in cell B35 to AF35 (merged cell) which indicates the month and year...but i guess i could just make changes to the B37 to AF37 to reflect the full date as in DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: @shariffa Understood. I will look into the non-full date retrieval; however, the multiple date selection is not possible as I explained above. The moment you change one cell, the macro will trigger so it won't be able to understand that you've changed mutliple cells. The best solution to this is to instead link the macro to a button to send the email  or a different even such as workbookSave

Comment: I will make do with the current code for the date as that part is working. I'm still trying to figure out the retrieval for the staff name. I have tried changing the code to 'Name: " Range ("A" & Target.Row).Value & "is applying for Ad-hoc leave on " & date1 &' the name retrieved is correct, but the date disappears.

Comment: @shariffa Ok try it again now. It should also return the DD/MM/YY format.